# Late 80s TV show/TV movie with a small devil or demon

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a TV show or maybe TV movie in in the mid 80s where a family was being tormented by a small (possibly devil) type demon. There was a scene where they caught it in a drinking glass like a spider in the kitchen (it was a very small demon). I may have some details wrong as I was a kid when I saw it.

Comment: Two possibles occur to me.  There was a Buffy episode with a very small demon and when her mentor, whose name escapes me, looks it up in a book the caption says "Actual Size".  The other is the last of three stories in the TV movie "Trilogy of Terror" in which a woman faces off against a demonic creature in the body of a Zuni fetish doll.  I'm not putting either of these as an answer, because neither involves a family,just trying to eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt -- Thanks for reminding me of ToT.  I'd been wondering for a long while what the title was.  Excellent acting by Karen Black, too!

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt:  The trilogy of terror one sounds like it could be it. I’m a bit fuzzy on the details of the movie. I was like 9 years old when I saw it. I’ll have to find where I can watch it. I

Answer (score 5):

Based on the OP's indication that it might be [Trilogy of Terror](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073820), I'm going to post it as an answer.

You can see the scene where the female protagonist traps the voodoo demon here;

There was also a sequel to it, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: The image of a demon trapped in a drinking glass seems oddly familiar to me - I can picture in my mind a tiny creature of some kind flailing against the sides of the glass with some sort of miniature sword. The suggested "Trilogy of Terror" doesn't match up for me because the Zuni fetish doll is too large for her to trap in that way. I'm wondering if there isn't another story which might be a closer match. Watching pieces of the linked "Trilogy of Terror" Youtube, I'm quite sure I've seen this movie before also.

Comment: Believe it or not, Trilogy of Terror is on Amazon Prime videos. I’m gonna watch it next weekend.